# Is there a version of glCopyImageSubData that uses blending in Openg GL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to copy one texture to another which is working. Now I'm attempting to copy a sprite that uses RGBA onto a map that uses RGB. When the RGBA Sprite get copied to the RGB map it's just a direct copy. What I'm looking for is a way to take a look at the alpha levels of the pixel and deal with it as it's supposed to be. Right now, though for now I'm just looking for a way to ignore the pixel copy if the pixel is supposed to be invisible. Is there another opengl function that'll do this or is there some sort of work around I do to make it work?

Would it be any easier to do something like this in direct or Vulcan?

Answer (score 3):

> as it's supposed to be

Who is to say what "it's supposed to be"? Who decides which pixels are "supposed" to be "invisible"?

As the name suggests, copy operations are supposed to copy the data as-is, not perform blending operations. If you want blending, then you're supposed to use a rendering operation. And this is just as true for Vulkan as OpenGL.